# При запуске теста в React'е возвращается ошибка от Jest

Tags: reactjs, юнит-тесты, axios, импорт, jest

Код теста

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';
// import axios from 'axios';

// jest.mock('axios');

test('renders app', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/latest news/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

при запуске выпадает такая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал добавлять config и прописывать там transformIgnorePattern как в документации Jest, пробовал уже много всего что нашел в интернете, проблему не решил. Может я что-то фундаментально не понимаю или Jest надо помочь работать и с импортом как-то. Памагите!!))

Comment: Пробовали бабель ставить? 
npm i -D @babel/preset-env //babel.config.js
module.exports = {presets: ['@babel/preset-env']}

Comment: Не помогло, пробовал еще @babel/preset-react тоже не помогает